# Efficient algorithm to expand $(x+a)^n$

Tags: algorithms, number-theory, coding-theory

im looking for efficient algorithm to expand $(x+a)^n$ without using binomial theorem

is the repeating square method efficient for that problem with the help of binary representation of n ?

Comment: This is very easy to find out. Just do it and count the operations.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you are asking?  What counts as "expanding $(x+a)^n$"?  What are the inputs, and what is the desired output?  Do you mean, given numbers $x,a,n$, you want to compute the value of $(x+a)^n$?  Or do you mean that, given the number $n$, you want to compute a symbolic expression for $(x+a)^n$, e.g., outputting a string like `x^n + n * a * x^(n-1) + ...` with the `...` filled in appropriately?